# How to make the allowed Values of a parameter depend on the selected value of another parameter in AWS Cloudformarion

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am very new to aws Cloud and CloudFormation.
I am trying to write a CloudFormation Template where a user can choose the DB Engine through a parameter.
Depending on the choice made by the user I would like the instance type to change accordingly.
For example:
Say part of my template looks like this:

```
Parameters:
Engine:
    Default: sqlserver-ex
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - sqlserver-se
      - sqlserver-ex
      - sqlserver-ee
DatabaseInstanceType:
    Default: db.t3.small
    AllowedValues:
      - db.t2.micro
      - db.t2.small
      - db.t2.medium
      - db.t2.large
      - db.t2.xlarge
```

When the user chooses the sqlserver-ex I only want the user to be able to choose an InstanceType like

```
db.t2.micro
dbt2.medium
db.t3.small
db.t3.xlarge
db.t2.micro
dbt2.medium
db.t3.small
db.t3.xlarge
```

Is this posible? 
Is it also posible to use that technique multiple times in a template?

I have searched for a solution for this for a few days with no luck and decided to ask the more advanced developers.
I hope that someone can clear this up for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no such functionality in CloudFormation.

Answer (score 1):

CloudFormation Template Constraint Rules enable cross-parameter validation:

https://www.cloudar.be/awsblog/undocumented-feature-using-template-constraint-rules-in-cloudformation

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/how-to-perform-cross-parameter-validation-using-aws-cloudformation-rules-and-assertions/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/servicecatalog/latest/adminguide/reference-template_constraint_rules.html

Comment: Hi Pat Thanks for your answer. I will read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

If the cross-parameter validation solution (provided by @Pat Myron https://stackoverflow.com/a/61874910/842075) works then of course it's better to use that solution.

### Original answer

Yes, possible but with tricks. Basically the trick is to replace two parameters with one parameter:

```yaml
Parameters:
  EngineAndInstanceType:
    Default: sqlserver-ex/db.t3.small
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - sqlserver-se/db.t2.micro
      - sqlserver-se/db.t2.small
      - sqlserver-se/db.t2.medium

      - sqlserver-ex/db.t3.micro
      - sqlserver-ex/db.t3.small
      - sqlserver-ex/db.t3.medium

      - sqlserver-ee/db.t2.large
      - sqlserver-ee/db.t2.xlarge
```

this of course will disable you from simply `!Ref`erencing engine and instance type later in template. You will have to use combination of `!Select` and `!Split` functions to be able to use one parameter in two different places:

```yaml
Resources:
  MyDB:
    Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBInstance'
    Properties:
      Engine: !Select [0, !Split ["/", !Ref EngineAndInstanceType]]
      DBInstanceClass: !Select [1, !Split ["/", !Ref EngineAndInstanceType]]
```